# Creating the right model for entities relating to themselves

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-5

I have the following classes in my model - but I cant get it to create tables the way I expect.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    private readonly BindingList<Dependancy> _dependancies = new BindingList<Dependancy>();
    public virtual BindingList<Dependancy> Dependancies
    {
        get { return _dependancies; }
    }
}

public class Dependancy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Task NeededTask { get; set; }
}
```

I want the Dependancy table just to contain the following fields;

```
Id,
Task_Id,
NeededTask_Id
```

however the generated one contains an extra Task_Id1  field

I have tried the following overide in the context class;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Dependancy>().HasRequired( p=>p.Task ).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasMany<Dependancy>(c => c.Dependancies).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

but the unwanted field is still created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework does not know that `Dependancy.Task` and `Task.Dependancies` are paired, so it creates two foreign key fields, one for both associations. You have to tell EF that both associations are counterparts:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dependancy>().HasRequired(p => p.Task)
    .WithMany(t => t.Dependancies).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The other association can be defined by

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dependancy>().HasOptional(p => p.NeededTask)
    .WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```